# Задача на словари

Tags: python, словари

Задача.

> Вопросы и ответы записаны в словаре в коде. В начале опроса спрашивается имя, под которым сохраняются все ответы. Ответы пишутся в файл csv, не перезаписывая прошлые.

Мне нужно, чтобы выводились на экран вопросы и возможные ответы, пользователь вводил ответ, после чего инфа с вопросом и его ответом сохранялась в словарь.
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как мне в словарь закинуть данные и вопроса и ответа.

я сделал со списком, точнее не доделал, но мне не нужен список, мне нужен словарь с вопросами и ответами. или быть может мне как-то модифицировать словари в списке, меняя  ключ answers, но как это сделать с переменной, кот зависит от ввода.

```
name = input('Enter name')
questions = [
{'question': 'Сколько вам лет', 'answers': ['18-25', '25-31', '31-40']},
{'question': 'Какой ваш рост', 'answers': ['150-160', '160-170', '170-190']},
{'question': 'Выберите ваш вес', 'answers': ['50-60', '60-70', '70-80']}]

answers = []

for q in questions:
for j in q:
    print(q[j])
ans = input()
answers.append(ans)


 data = [{
name: answers}]

with open('poll.csv', 'a') as f:
fieldnames = [name]
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

можно вот так изменить словарь

```
questions = {'Сколько вам лет': {1:'18-25', 2:'25-31', 3:'31-40', 4:'100-140'},
                'Какой ваш рост': {1:'150-160', 2:'160-170', 3:'170-190'},
                'Выберите ваш вес': {1:'50-60', 2:'60-70', 3:'70-80'}
            }

def my_test(name):
    all_a = {}
    answer = {name:all_a}
    for q in questions:
        print(f'{q}, {name}')
        print('Выберите ответ')
        for ans in questions[q]:
            print(f'{ans} - {questions[q][ans]}')
        answ = input()
        if questions[q][int(answ)]:
            all_a[q] = questions[q][int(answ)]
        else:
            print('такого варианта нет')
        print()
    return answer

print(my_test(input('Enter name \n')))
```

Только надо еще будет что-то добавить если пользователь введет неверный ответ.
Ну и запись в файл тоже, но с записью думаю справитесь.

Comment: Этот вариант тоже не совсем верен. Нужно, чтобы после опроса, был словарь с именем в виде ключа и в качеств значений словарь с вопросами и ответами

Comment: @НикитаСмяцкий ну это же элементарно дописать . У вас в цикле есть сам вопрос `q` и в конце вы получаете на него ответ `answ`.  Или у вас возникают проблемы с созданием нового словаря и записи в него?

Comment: видимо, что-то не доходит до меня как мой ответ записать, переменная имеет одно название, а ответы всегда разные.

Comment: @НикитаСмяцкий изменил ответ